# Getting and Setting a Factory value/object in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Part of this is includes the question of whether or not this is possible, but I am trying to make a factory value called currentUser, which will hold a single use from userService. I am trying to figure out how to make this interaction occur.

If my factories are as follows:

```
app.factory('currentUser', function() {

});

app.factory('userService', function() {
  return {
    users: [{
      name: "John",
      password: "12",
      email: "test@example.com",
      phone: "238-491-2138"
    }, {
      name: "Austin",
      password: "potaoes",
      email: "example@gmail.com",
      phone: "138-490-1251"
    }]

  };
});
```

and I have a controller that does the following, is there a way to put `currentuser = userService.users[i];`. Or if this is a terrible way of doing it, how might I setup a way to keep track of a "current user"?

```
  $scope.login = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < userService.users.length; i++) {
      if (userService.users[i].email.toLowerCase() === $scope.credentials.email.toLowerCase()) {
        if (userService.users[i].password === $scope.credentials.password) {
          $scope.messageLogin = "Success!";
          $timeout(function() {
            $timeout(function() {
              $location.path("/account");
            }, 500)
            $scope.loggedIn = true;
            $scope.messageLogin = "Redirecting...";

            //  currentUser == userService.users[i];

          }, 500)
        } else {
          $scope.messageLogin = "Incorrect login details";
        }
        return;
      }
    }
    $scope.messageLogin = "Username does not exist";
  };
```

Not sure if this is possible due to the fact that the factory seems to always have a `return` and never a get/set scenario. So if this is a bad use for Factory, how should I go about it?

Comment: Why the excessive use of $timeout? Is it strictly to introduce some delay in messages appearing and the redirect occurring? Seems like this is attempting to solve a problem that would be better solved with promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options. You can make it part of the user service itself:

```
app.factory('userService', function() {
  var currentUser;

  return {
    getCurrentUser: function() {
      return currentUser;
    },
    setCurrentUser: function(user) {
      currentUser = user;
    },
    users: [{
      name: "John",
      password: "12",
      email: "test@example.com",
      phone: "238-491-2138"
    }, {
      name: "Austin",
      password: "potaoes",
      email: "example@gmail.com",
      phone: "138-490-1251"
    }]

  };
});
```

or you can store it in a separate object:

```
app.factory('currentUser', function() {
  var currentUser;

  return {
    getCurrentUser: function() {
      return currentUser;
    },
    setCurrentUser: function(user) {
      currentUser = user;
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Services/Factories in AngularJS are singletons](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services), so you should build your application with the expectation that a service will always resolve to the same value.

That being said, your service is just a JavaScript object and its fields/properties are mutable. I don't see anything wrong with adding a field called "current" to your "userService", which is designed to contain a reference to the current user.